# How to simulate mouseMove on d3 component for testing in react

Tags: reactjs, testing, d3.js, enzyme

I would like to test a component that uses D3 which reports on the competent relative coordinates of a `mouseMove` event. This component works as expected in the browser -- I have a simple callback that logs the coordinates and the a 'Mouse moved' event is also recorded:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { mouse, select } from 'd3-selection';

class Overlay extends Component {
  _handleMouseMove(coordinates, callback) {
    console.log('Mouse moved');
    callback(coordinates);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.renderD3Move();
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.renderD3Move();
  }

  renderD3Move() {
    const handleMouseMove = this._handleMouseMove;
    const callback = this.props.callback;
    const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    select(node).on('mousemove', function handleMouse() {
      handleMouseMove(mouse(node), callback);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <rect
        className="overlay"
        height={this.props.height}
        width={this.props.width}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Overlay;
```

Despite this, I am unable to write a test that triggers the callback or even get the 'Mouse moved' message to log:

```
import chai from 'chai';
chai.should();
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import Overlay from '.';

describe('<Overlay />', function() {
  var height = 50,
    width = 50;

  it('passes mouse coordinates when mouse moves', function() {
    const callback = sinon.spy();
    var wrapper = mount(
      <Overlay height={height} width={width} callback={callback} />
    );
    wrapper.find('Overlay').simulate('mousemove');
    wrapper.find('rect').simulate('mousemove');
    wrapper.find('Overlay').simulate('mouseMove');
    wrapper.find('rect').simulate('mouseMove');
    callback.called.should.equal(true);
  });
}
```

**My questions are:**

1. Is there a way to trigger mouseMove in the component from the test?
2. If so, can I also test the coordinates of the mouseMove event?
3. If there is a fundamental incompatibility with how I'm implementing the component, is there a best practice for how to determine the coordinates of a mouseMove event relative to the node that can be easily tested?

*Related questions that don't fully address what I'm asking*

- [This asks a related question about mouseMove but the dispatchEvent approach doesn't seem to work on nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055738/react-testutils-how-can-i-simulate-document-mousemove)
- [This seems to be a solution for determining the position of mouse coordinates but may be challenging to integrate into react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16154857/how-can-i-get-the-mouse-co-ordinates-relative-to-a-parent-div-javascript)
- [And this one leads me to be more confident that its not trivial to determine coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939133/how-do-you-reliably-measure-react-components-for-computed-position-of-popovers-a)